# Monogame / XNA - Multple 2D Cameras (Rectangle) on screen

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, camera, monogame

I recently started building a simple 2D roguelike game using Monogame 3.4. I was keen on building the game "engine" myself as I saw it as a fun learning curve. Monogame was pretty much the best option for me to get started as I'm a C# dev by profession.
After getting my sprite to run around on the screen, I figured I probably need a proper level to continue with the more interesting stuff. So I decided to build a level builder for the game.

I've been struggling and digging around tutorials regarding building a 2D Camera.

I used this camera [tutorial](http://www.david-gouveia.com/portfolio/limiting-2d-camera-movement-with-zoom/) and I preferred this specific implementation.
My only problem is, currently, I have two Rectangles (Cameras) on my screen.

[image]

The Rectangle on the left represents a scrollable panel with all the available sprites but is also a sort of overlay. Underneath it, the level "map" is drawn.
My question is simply, how would I enable my level Rectangle to scroll past the overlay to view the left-hand side of it, which is currently being obscured by the panel.

Relevant code files are [here](https://gist.github.com/fjlaubscher/f0b38f139b6f2f1f5b3b)

I would appreciate all the help I can get. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this by using Viewports when drawing the Rectangles / Cameras

```
        GraphicsDevice.Viewport = new Viewport(_level);

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null, _camera.ViewMatrix);
        DrawLevelTiles();
        spriteBatch.End();

        GraphicsDevice.Viewport = new Viewport(_panel);

        // draw panel
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null, null);
        _spritePanel.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        // draw tiles to panel
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null, _panelCamera.ViewMatrix);
        DrawTiles();
        spriteBatch.End();
```